# How can I convert a half-hour timezone to a pytz timezone object?

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, pytz

I am trying to read times with their timezone specified by its UTC-offset and store them as python datetimes.

The `pytz` module provides the available timezones and I think the complete list is given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13866926/1484957).  If so, most of the times can be stored by using the corresponding `Etc/` timezone and flipping the sign:

```
Etc/GMT
Etc/GMT+0
Etc/GMT+1
Etc/GMT+10
Etc/GMT+11
Etc/GMT+12
Etc/GMT+2
Etc/GMT+3
Etc/GMT+4
Etc/GMT+5
Etc/GMT+6
Etc/GMT+7
Etc/GMT+8
Etc/GMT+9
Etc/GMT-0
Etc/GMT-1
Etc/GMT-10
Etc/GMT-11
Etc/GMT-12
Etc/GMT-13
Etc/GMT-14
Etc/GMT-2
Etc/GMT-3
Etc/GMT-4
Etc/GMT-5
Etc/GMT-6
Etc/GMT-7
Etc/GMT-8
Etc/GMT-9
```

However, some timezones, like Newfoundland Standard Time and Afghanistan Time are half-hour offsets from GMT (-3:30 and +4:30, respectively).  How can I store these times with their appropriate timezone without manually mapping these specific offsets to `America/St_Johns` or `Asia/Kabul`?

Comment: So you don't want to use something like `pytz.timezone("Canada/Newfoundland")` ?

Comment: I'd rather not. The data is given in GMT offset, so I'd have to manually set up mappings of each of these offsets to the correct city.  Not a big chore but it seems like there should be a way that doesn't require knowledge of geography.

Answer (score 1):

There is something oyu can do, although not exactly what you seem to want.

```
>>> nf_offset = pytz.FixedOffset(-150) # offset is in minutes, so 150=2.5 hours
>>> nf_tz = pytz.datetime("Canada/Newfoundland")
>>> datetime.now(nf_tz).strftime("%H:%M") == datetime.now(nf_offset).strftime("%H:%M")
True
```

They are different objects, so it's not certain you can do what you're hoping after this point, but this will get you a generic object from which you can compare times at arbitrary offsets from UTC.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `Etc/GMT±h` POSIX timezones. [They are present only for historical reasons (and perhaps for ships in the sea)](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/etcetera).

In general, utc offset is not enough to specify a timezone i.e., the same timezone may have *different* utc offsets at different times. And in reverse, multiple timezones may have the same utc offset at some point.

If you are given a fixed utc offset *with* corresponding dates then you could use [any `FixedOffset` implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23122493/4279).

If you want to get the correct time for other dates then you have to map your input data to the correct timezone ids such as `'America/St_Johns'`. See [pytz: return Olson Timezone name from only a GMT Offset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30315485/4279).